# Change theme template for one form

Tags: 8, theming, forms

I try to change a the theme template for one form. I do not want to use theme suggestions as I only want to use a different theme in one case, and if I add a suggestion, it is always used. (maybe I'm wrong.)

I'm doing:

in my controller:

```
$form = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($entity);

$form['#theme_wrappers'][] = 'user_register_form_01';

return $form;
```

in my .module

```
function mymodule_theme() {
  return [
    'user_register_form_01' => [
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'user-register-form-01',
    ],
  ];
}
```

in user-register-form-01.html.twig:

```
<form{{ attributes }}>

  {{ form.field_1 }}
  {{ form.field_2 }}
  {{ form.account.pass }}
  {{ form.account.mail }}

  {{ form.form_build_id }}
  {{ form.form_id }}
  {{ form.actions }}

</form>
```

Everything seems to be rendered correctly, but the form does not work/submit. I think it is because attributes does not contain any action information. There is one more attributes variable inside form but I don't know how to call it as when I dump it it is prefixed with #

dump(form|keys) returns

```
array (size=49)
  0 => string '#attributes' (length=11)
  1 => string '#attached' (length=9)
  ...
  47 => string '#children' (length=9)
```

1. I don't know how to access this as form.#attributes doesn't work and form.attributes results empty.
2. Also this #attributes seems not to contain the needed form submission information. But it seems that inside #children the #attributes does.

I am thankfull for any hint or help.

Comment: That would render a `<form>` within a `<form>` wouldn't it? That's invalid HTML and might explain the failure to submit properly (you don't need an action or method on a `<form>` tag, the form will still submit as those attributes have default values). You probably just want `$form['#theme'] = 'user_register_form_01';`

Comment: already tried, if I use $form['#theme'] my template is not used at all

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the Context module for this (https://www.drupal.org/project/context)? One of the "reactions" is to change the theme. You can do it by system path.